# Is double-checked locking on ConcurrentHashMap thread-safe?

Tags: java

In many cases implementing double-checked-locking in Java [is not thread safe](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html) (the unsynchronized section of code can return partially initialized values).  However, I'm using double-checked locking to check if a value is in a `ConcurrentHashMap`, and if it isn't, then enter a synchronized block, create the object, and `put` it in the map.  Is this thread safe?  That is, will the `put` or `get` method in `ConcurrentHashMap` ever add or return partially constructed values (or do some other unexpected behavior)?  Or are the `get` and `put` methods atomic, i.e. a successful `put` guarantees that other threads will see the properly constructed object that was put in the map?  Code is as follows:

```
public class MyClass {

    private static ConcurrentHashMap<KeyObject, SingletonObject> myConcurrentMap = new Concurrent...

    ...

    private static SingletonValue getFromConcurrentMap(KeyObject key) {

        SingletonValue singleton = this.myConcurrentHashMap.get(key);
        if (singleton == null) {
            synchronized (this.myConcurrentHashMap) {
                singleton = this.myConcurrentHashMap.get(domainRuleBase);
                if (singleton == null) {
                    singleton = SingletonValue.buildNewInstance();
                    this.myConcurrentHashMap.put(key, singleton);
                }
            }
        }
        return singleton;
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Also I would read this [doc](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/jsr166/dist/docs/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) for more details.

Comment: I blv by double locking you can just use regular `HashMap` which is faster than `ConcurrentHashMap`

Comment: yes thanks, though what really convinced me was the [ConcurrentMap documentation](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/jsr166/dist/docs/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html): "memory consistency effects: As with other concurrent collections, actions in a thread prior to placing an object into a ConcurrentMap as a key or value happen-before actions subsequent to the access or removal of that object from the ConcurrentMap in another thread."

Comment: This could almost, but not quite, be replaced by `myConcurrentHashMap.merge(key, SingletonValue.buildNewInstance(), (value, instance) -> value != null ? value : this.myConcurrentHashMap.getOrDefault(domainRuleBase, instance));` I would take a good look at `computeIfAbsent`, `putIfAbsent`, `merge`, and `getOrDefault` if I were you. A suitable application of those newer methods of `Map` may obviate the need for both the locking, tests, and logic.